# Relevant Command in Rational Team Concert corresponding to clearcase macros

Tags: clearcase, rtc

I want to know whether we can use the ClearCase macros in Rational Team Concert itself for communicating from scripts. Example for fetching the baseline details.
     Does Change Management Integration (CMI) will help on this. Please shed your views.

Answer (score 0):

Not the I know of.

For fetching baselines or any other RTC-related operation, you would use [`scm` or `lscm`](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fr_scm_cli_scm.html) (which is the equivalent of `cleartool`, or more specifically `rcleartool` in CCRC).

See more with the article "[Using the Jazz SCM command line to support software configuration audit](https://jazz.net/library/article/978)":

> To list the baselines associated with all components present in a stream/workspace, run `lscm` list baselines with `-w/--workspace` option.

```
$ lscm ls baselines -w "JUnit Stream" -r localhost
Component: (5630) "JUnit Releng"
  Baseline: (5631) 2 "Initial Snapshot for JUnit Releng"   ""  ADMIN  Jun 6, 2012 12:37:58 PM
  Baseline: (5639) 1 "Initial Baseline for JUnit Releng"   "Initial Baseline of Component JUnit Releng"  ADMIN  Jun 6, 2012 12:33:34 PM
Component: (5632) "JUnit Source"
  Baseline: (5633) 5 "Milestone-1"   "Baseline created as part of Milestone-1 Snapshot"  ADMIN  Jun 6, 2012 12:47:23 PM
  Baseline: (5634) 4 "Vector.java Modification-2"   "Vector.java Modification-2"  ADMIN  Jun 6, 2012 12:46:10 PM
  Baseline: (5635) 3 "Vector.java Modification-1"   "Vector.java Modification-1"  ADMIN  Jun 6, 2012 12:43:40 PM
  Baseline: (5636) 2 "Initial Snapshot for JUnit Source"   "Initial Snapshot for JUnit Source"  ADMIN  Jun 6, 2012 12:37:58 PM
  Baseline: (5637) 1 "Initial Baseline for JUnit Source"   "Initial Baseline of Component JUnit"  ADMIN  Jun 6, 2012 12:28:05 PM
```

Comment: Does lscm commands can be used from scripts to fetch information from RTC?

Comment: @JavaeinA can you give an example of "ClearCase macro"?

Comment: Example macros command to fetch latest baseline from a stream:   cleartool lsstream -fmt %latest_blsCXp stream_name@\pvob

Comment: @JavaeinA I confirm: my answer stands: cleartool means lscm in RTC.